# Guardian permissions in phoenix app

Tags: api, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following in my users controller:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions, 
  handler: MyAppWeb.AuthController, admin: [:manage_users]

def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = method_to_find_user

  conn
  |> json(user)
end
```

So with this code, guardian will send a 401 when a user without the :manage_users permission tries to access any users show page. What I am trying to do is allow the current user to be able to view his/her self. I have the current user but not sure where/how to implement this feature.

Would this logic be placed in the handler's unauthorized method or am I missing something simple?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are returning a 401 error for a non-error condition (user trying to view self). I'd change the approach so that the 401 is returned only if unauthorized user tries to show another account. This is preferable to returning an error, but having the error page do something useful (if I'm reading you right).

Comment: Ya i think the issue is more about Guardian itself. I don't really control when the 401 is sent. I can easily put a case statement around the first two lines and solve my issue. With ruby i could just make a method and append it to a 'when' statement. Ex: 'when action is show' AND some_method_is true, however elixir doesn't allow ambiguous methods here and for good reason. I guess im just looking for a more elegant way to solve a seemingly common issue. Thanks for your reply!